# Mistake with insertion sort realisation in C

Tags: insertion

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int unsorted[] = {1,3,4,5,2};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        temp = unsorted[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while(unsorted[j] > unsorted[i]){
                unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
                unsorted[j] = temp;
            }

}
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%i", unsorted[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 13425. It's entering the while loop enough times to move the 2(the last element) to its place, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: `for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){ temp = unsorted[i];` It may not be related to your current issue, but consider what will happen when the value of `i` reaches 5.

Comment: I hadn't think about this, I add a if contidion so if i <= 4 it will check the condition of the while loop. But as you said this didn't fix the issue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int unsorted[] = {1,3,4,5,2};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        j = i;
        while(j>0 && unsorted[j]<unsorted[j-1]){
                temp = unsorted[j];
                unsorted[j] = unsorted[j-1];
                unsorted[j-1] = temp;
                j--;
            }

}
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d", unsorted[i]);
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 mistakes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int unsorted[] = {1,3,4,5,2};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        temp = unsorted[i]; // You are out of array boundaries here
        j = i - 1;
        while(unsorted[j] > unsorted[i]){
            // you need to place j-th element in (j+1)-th
            // position, but not in i-th position
            unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
            unsorted[j] = temp; // you can do this one time after end of this cycle
            // You need to decrement j in this cycle until j >= 0
        }

    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%i", unsorted[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to place j-th element in (j+1)-th
position, but not in i-th position / I didn't understand those j + 1 == i / And why I should change the unsorted[j] with temp after the end of the cicle, if unsorted[j] is in-place?

Comment: j + 1 == i is truth only on first iteration of the while loop. After first iteration j decreases.

Comment: You should do this in cycle unsorted[j+1] = unsorted[j]; but unsorted[j] = temp; you can do only once